# Python argparse cut half of argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to enter sha512 hash as an argument but argparse just cut off half of it for no reason. When I enter Unix hash( MiqkFWCm1fNJI ) it works as it supposed. I tried to search for something like this but didn't find anything.
My code for command line arguments looks like this :

```
def check_args():
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse.add_argument('-p', '--password', type=str, action='store', help='enter your hashed password: -p your_hash')
    parse.add_argument('-w', '--wordlist', help='add your wordlist: -w wordlist')
    parse.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='file with hashes: -f your_hashes')

    args_list = parse.parse_args()

    return args_list
```

Part of code where it's used:

```
    c_arg = check_args()

    psw = c_arg.password
    wordlist = c_arg.wordlist
    file = c_arg.file
    print(psw)
```

so when I run script

```
python crack.py -p $6$krVh8s..$ttQmt30au3s9wHywp/KGdFKGe1WoEK4xpFJupMA.I06/tdv1//4x7e1gSU2e2Qu/1kQ0rfqXRxghfBX0Io1BJ.
```

I get this output:

```
../KGdFKGe1WoEK4xpFJupMA.I06/tdv1//4x7e1gSU2e2Qu/1kQ0rfqXRxghfBX0Io1BJ.
```

which should be:

```
 $6$krVh8s..$ttQmt30au3s9wHywp/KGdFKGe1WoEK4xpFJupMA.I06/tdv1//4x7e1gSU2e2Qu/1kQ0rfqXRxghfBX0Io1BJ.
```

if I run same script with argument like this it works as supposed:

```
python crack.py -p MiqkFWCm1fNJI
```

Output:

```
MiqkFWCm1fNJI
```

What can be wrong about this and how can I make argparse read this kind of strings?

Comment: Check the `sys.argv`.  The problem is most likely in how the shell pass the strings to Python.  `argparse` doesn't do any sort of clipping or cutting like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `argparse` or Python.

`$6` and the like are references to [non-existent] environment variables in Unix/Linux. Their values are `''` (empty strings). Enclose your entire hash in single quotation marks to protect the data from being interpreted by the shell: `'$6$krVh8s..$ttQmt30au3s9wHywp/...'`.